# Saving base64 encoded image for facebook sharing via PHP

Tags: php, facebook, image, base64

I have an image thumbnail, encoded as base64, that I want to use as the default thumbnail when sharing a page via Facebook.  Facebook does not seem to support using the base64 image directly so I need to render/save/decode(?) it first before the user can click the "share" button.  Any thoughts?

Here's my thumbnail:

```
$thumbnail = '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,' . $thumbnail_src . '" />';
```

Obviously it renders fine in the browser but Facebook can't "get it."

Comment: Someone just voted this down...did I post something incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up decoding the image and writing it to a temporary directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the GD Library first. And then create a php page that will render the image with the correct header so Facebook will see this as an image.